# java extend static method, can't compile, why?

Tags: java

```java
class Base {
    public static void f(){}
}
class Derived extends Base{
    private static void f(){}
}
```

the Derived.f()'s modifier must be public, if it's private ,the compiler say
*"attempting to assign weaker access privileges; was public"*.
I can't understand! Why compiler not allow us to do that?

Comment: I'm guessing it's to prevent a confusing scenario where the method invoked by `Derived.f()` would depend on the distance of the caller.

Comment: There is no such thing as extending methods in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static methods can't be overridden , those can only be hidden by the subclasses and accessability of a method has nothing to do with hiding.Only instance methods can be overridden but methods are hidden or overridden based on the signatures and in both the cases signatures should be same.You can't reduce the accessibility of an inherited method whether it's hidden or overridden.

Answer (score 1):

It's a fundamental principle in OOP, that you are not allowed to assign weaker access modifier (here is `private`) in subclass than in superclass (here is `public`) when you **override methods**.

This is irrelevant to the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) (LSP), that is a concept in Object Oriented Programming that states: *functions that use pointers or references to base classes must be able to use objects of derived classes without knowing it.*

So it could be:

```
public class Base {
    private static void f() {
    }
}

class Derived extends Base {
    public static void f() {    // as well as protected, default, private
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a perfect answer for the case where the method isn't static.